# NHibernate keeps losing the timezone of my DateTime in PostgreSQL 9.0

Tags: c#, nhibernate, postgresql, timezone

I need to convince NHibernate to store the timezone of the `DateTime` values I am persisting. The columns are `timestamp with time zone`.

We have a convention that we only store UTC DateTimes in the database, so we were using `timestamp without time zone` but I needed the database to represent know the timezone so a report that access the database directly would be able to perform correctly.

I've tried telling NHibernate I have a custom type for `DateTime` as follows:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class UtcDateTimeUserType<T> : IUserType
    {
        private static readonly SqlType[] MySqlTypes = {SqlTypeFactory.DateTime };

        public SqlType[] SqlTypes
        {
            get { return MySqlTypes; }
        }

        public System.Type ReturnedType
        {
            get { return typeof(T); }
        }

        public bool IsMutable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public object DeepCopy(object value)
        {
            return value; // DateTime is immutable
        }

        public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
        {
            return object.Equals(x, y);
        }

        public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader resultSet,
                                  string[] names,
                                  object owner)
        {
            int index0 = resultSet.GetOrdinal(names[0]);
            if (resultSet.IsDBNull(index0))
            {
                return null;
            }
            var value = resultSet.GetDateTime(index0);
            return DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        }

        public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand statement,
                                object value,
                                int index)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                ((IDbDataParameter)statement.Parameters[index]).Value = DBNull.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                var dateTime = (DateTime)value;
                if (dateTime == DateTime.MinValue) dateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                if (dateTime.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(
                        "Attempting to save a datetime without a Kind set.. what time zone are you in?");
                ((IDbDataParameter) statement.Parameters[index]).Value = dateTime.ToUniversalTime();

            }
        }

        public object Disassemble(object value)
        {
            return value;
        }

        public object Assemble(object cached, Object owner)
        {
            return cached;
        }

        public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
        {
            return original;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Object x)
        {
            return x.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    public class NullableUtcDateTimeUserTypeConvention
  : UserTypeConvention<UtcDateTimeUserType<DateTime?>>
    {
    }

    public class UtcDateTimeUserTypeConvention
  : UserTypeConvention<UtcDateTimeUserType<DateTime>>
    {
    }
```

#### Fluent NHibernateConfiguration

```
    autoPersistenceModel = autoPersistenceModel.Conventions.Setup(s =>
                               {
                                   s.Add<TableNameConvention>();
                                   s.Add<PrimaryKeyConvention>();
                                   s.Add<CustomForeignKeyConvention>();
                                   s.Add<CascadeConvention>();
                                   s.Add<CalculatedFieldPropertyConvention>();
                                   s.Add<UtcDateTimeUserTypeConvention>();
                                   s.Add<NullableUtcDateTimeUserTypeConvention>();
                                   s.AddAssembly(assembly);
                               });
```

This catches code trying to persist datetimes without The Timezone set. It also ensures all `DateTime`s are UTC before going into the database, and correctly sets them to UTC on the way back out.

But the following statement does not work:

```
((IDbDataParameter) statement.Parameters[index]).Value = dateTime.ToUniversalTime();
```

This is still `Unspecified` after assignment:

```
((DateTime)((IDbDataParameter) statement.Parameters[index]).Value).Kind
```

I notice from NHibernate's code that the PostgresDialect has the following:

```
 RegisterColumnType(DbType.DateTime, "timestamp");
```

but nothing mentions `timestamp with time zone` or `timestamptz`.

How to I make NHibernate persist DateTimes with their time zone into Postgres9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the NpgSQL driver has a bug:

The assignment `((IDbDataParameter) statement.Parameters[index]).Value = dateTime.ToUniversalTime();` calls the `set` on the Value property. This converts the `DateTime` to a `NpgsqlTimeStamp` and stores it, then converts that back to a `System.DatetTime` and stores that in the value.

The problem is that it's using `NpgsqlTimeStamp` not `NpgsqlTimeStampTZ`, so it loses the time zone information.

Comment: Do you know if this has now been addressed?